# How to delete all lines containing the leading // or /

Tags: python, split, character

I have a file trial.txt containing

```
This can stay
// but this 
/ and this
// must go
I will be happy
```

To remove leading # I used in other cases

```
os.system(" sed '/^#.*/d' trial.txt > start.txt ")
```

so to remove // I used

```
os.system(" sed '/^//.*/d' trial.txt > start.txt ")
```

but this gives error

```
sed: 1: "/^//.*/d": invalid command code /
```

Any suggestions? with preferably Python or with Linux?

Comment: you could have been fine with a ```'^/.*'```. To get those ones that should go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you have to escape slash, don't escape slash with ... another slash (and use raw string prefix)

```
os.system("sed r'/^\/.*/d' trial.txt > start.txt")
```

But that's not very pythonic for many reasons:

- `os.system` is deprecated in favor of `subprocess`
- your command line depends on the shell, so vulnerable to attacks if some fields become variable
- using `sed` when Python can do it natively is overkill (also not portable, example on windows where `sed` must be installed separately, and the single quotes also won't work there...)

Besides that doesn't filter out the single slashed line.

I'd go with testing `/` on the start of each line and use `writelines` with a generator comprehension:

```
with open("trial.txt") as fr, open("start.txt","w") as fw:
    fw.writelines(line for line in fr if not line.startswith("/"))
```